# is there an equivalent for__getattr__ to intercept accesses to a python class's static attributes?

Tags: python

python magic method `__getattr__` lets one intercept calls to access attributes of objects. Is there an equivalent to do the same for class attributes?

IMO not a duplicate to intercept calls to undefined methods. class variables are different than methods. I want to intercept calls of pattern A.x where A is the class and 'x' is the attribute. –

Comment: The equivalent is ... `__getattr__`   :)

Comment: IMO not a duplicate. class variables are different than methods. I want to intercept calls of pattern A.x where A is the class and 'x' is the attribute.

Comment: That's just `__getattr__` on the type though.